# Get controls in a separate class of the main Activity using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, xml, android-asynctask

I need to get the controls to change the values in the layout. But going by the context parameter for the class it does not find the controls declared in xml returning null for each cast made.

The class where I am trying to recover this data extends AsyncTask:

```
public class WSCatalogo91 extends AsyncTask<Void, ProgressAux, Boolean> 

private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private TextView mProgressText;

public WSCatalogo91(WSCatalogo91Listener listener) throws SQLException {
        this.listener = listener;
        dh = new DatabaseHelper((Activity) listener);
        confDao = new ConfiguracaoDao(dh.getConnectionSource());
        pDao = new ProdutoDao(dh.getConnectionSource());

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) ((Activity) listener).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressText = (TextView) ((Activity) listener).findViewById(R.id.progressBarTextView);
        auxProgresso = new ProgressAux();
    }
```

mProgressBar and mProgressText are null, but my context is not null, so that it is being used in lines up perfectly. Follows the xml code which declare the ids.

```
<TextView android:text="@string/progressBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarTextView"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:maxHeight="400dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />
```

This shows that there is a progressBar and progressBarTextView:
[image: This shows that there is a progressBar nor progressBarTextView]

WSCatalogo91 class:

```
  public class WSCatalogo91 extends AsyncTask<Void, ProgressAux, Boolean> {

      public WSCatalogo91(WSCatalogo91Listener listener) throws SQLException {
            this.listener = listener;
        dh = new DatabaseHelper((Activity) listener);
        confDao = new ConfiguracaoDao(dh.getConnectionSource());
        pDao = new ProdutoDao(dh.getConnectionSource());

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) ((Activity)listener).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressText = (TextView) ((Activity) listener).findViewById(R.id.progressBarTextView);
        auxProgresso = new ProgressAux();
        }

        private Bitmap baixarImagens(String urlComplement, String tDownload, int totalImages) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(ProgressAux... params) {
            if(params[0].getTexto() != null)
            mProgressText.setText(params[0].getTexto());

            mProgressBar.setProgress(params[0].getProgresso());
        }

        private String saveImagesIntoInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String imgName) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ...
        }

        private void saveChanges() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... paths) {
            ...
        }

        private AtualizarJSON DeserializaConsultaAtualizacao(String resultadoJSON) throws JSONException {
           ...
        }

        private <T> List<T> DeserializaConsulta(Class<T[]> tipo, String resultadoJSON) throws JSONException {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
           ...
        }

        public interface WSCatalogo91Listener {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `AsyncTask` should not directly manipulate UI components, particularly outside of the `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate` callbacks. Since you are already using a callback listener interface your `Activity` implements, it would be simpler just to let the `Activity` manipulate it's UI components on callback. Be sure you cover the life cycle cases as `AsyncTask` is not aware of the `Activity` life cycle and needs to be canceled appropriately.

Comment: I know what you said, but I need to manipulate the onProgressUpdate () the same, but need to get in the constructor the fields that want to manipulate, as would be using several times during the process and making several changes. I'm doing it to update on a download progress bar and also a textView feedback.

So not want every time you enter the onProgressUpdate () redo the search and the cast ... There's no way to do what I'm doing and would have to use this form?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do something like what you have coded, but it makes an unnecessary tight coupling between your interface and your activity (negating the benefit of the interface). There will also be potential race conditions in play with respect to life cycle and layout inflation, which complicates this.

Comment: Please put the solution in response, I am new to Android and I think important to keep separate the classes, but if there is no other way, tell me how.

Comment: See above: use your existing listener implementation (callback interface the `Activity` implements) to manipulate the UI rather than using this cast approach.